# How do I run a script (that needs WIFI) on shutdown before WIFI is down

Tags: networking, wifi, init.d

I have a script on the PI to shutdown my NAS "shutdown_nas.sh".
I have created that script in /etc/init.d according to the instructions in
/etc/init.d/README

It is symlinked in /etc/rc0.d/K01NAS_shutdown.sh

It works fine when I call:

```
sudo service shutdown_nas.sh stop
```

It also works fine when I halt the PI when I'm on ethernet (eth0).

It ***doesn't*** work on WIFI only, it seems like wlan is down before the needed request is done.

Comment: I think you need a higher runlevel. Try `/etc/rc2.d/K01NAS_shutdown.sh`, or `/etc/rc3.d/K01NAS_shutdown.sh`

Comment: I fail to see that. It should run on shutdown, rc0.d. 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runlevels

Comment: I don't really understand runlevels that well. Reading a bit more, I think you're right. Is `K01...` the first file in the rc2.d directory? Is there a `K00..` that messes thins up?

Comment: No, and the script does work (mutatis mutandis) on a Ubuntu 14.04 laptop, so it must be a RPI thing. Maybe because the dongle is on a USB-hub

Answer (score 1):

Change the sequence number of your service so it is called before the wifi service.

```
man update-rc.d
```